# Failed to create view

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, ddl

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ALL_INTERRUPTED_DATA AS
select
    trigger_info_A.b1,
    trigger_info_A.b2,
    trigger_info_A.B3TEXT,
    trigger_info_A.elem,
    trigger_info_B.b1,
    trigger_info_B.b2,
    trigger_info_B.B3TEXT,
    trigger_info_B.elem,
    oms_source.source_code,
    energization_info.b1,
    energization_info.b2,
    energization_info.b3text,
    to_char(energization_info.deenergized_date,'DD-MM-YYYY Hh24:MI:SS'),
    to_char(energization_info.energized_date,'DD-MM-YYYY Hh24:MI:SS'),
    oms_source.connected_customer,
    trigger_info_A.comments
from
    energization_info,
    trigger_info trigger_info_A,
    trigger_info trigger_info_B,
    oms_source
where
    (
        energization_info.trigger_number = trigger_info_A.trigger_number
    )
    and (
        energization_info.ENERGIZED_TRIGGER_NUMBER = trigger_info_B.trigger_number
    )
    and (
        energization_info.b1 = oms_source.B1NAME
        and energization_info.b2 = oms_source.B2NAME
        and energization_info.b3 = oms_source.B3NAME
    ) WITH READ ONLY;
```

trigger_info_B.b1,trigger_info_B.b2,trigger_info_B.B3TEXT,trigger_info_B.elem,

> `ERROR at line 3:`
> `ORA-00957: duplicate column name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see the duplicate names in the select clause.

Example:

```
trigger_info_A.b1
trigger_info_B.b1
```

While creating the view, each columns in select must have different name/alias.

Try to find such duplicate names of columns and give them different names using alias.

Example:

```
trigger_info_A.b1 as A_b1
trigger_info_B.b1 as B_b1
```

Comment: After creating the alias, I am getting this error `ERROR at line 5: ORA-00998: must name this expression with a colum alias`

Comment: Now, that must be different error. The question is asked for duplicate column name. And it is resolved (seems so). You can ask new question with updated query and error.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much.